# Error in login logout system

Tags: php, sql

When I am submitting the form then I am landing on login.php and getting so many errors.

I have put errors on following link:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1AqwZ71iAQgZGMU-W0Go6czbpgGenF_f7ucgmEFw0AHo/edit

I am newbie and struggling for last 5 hours with above code.
I have following pages in my login logout system:

db.php

```
<?php 
$conn=new mysqli('localhost','root','','people');
?>
```

index.php

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    ?>
    <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <form method="post" name="login" action="login.php">
    <label for="name" class="labelname"> Username </label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="userid" required="required" /><br />
    <label for="name" class="labelname"> Password </label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="passid" required="required"  /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit"  value="Login" />
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

login.php

```
<?php 
include('db.php');
session_start();
{
    $user=mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $pass=mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
    $fetch=mysqli_query("SELECT id FROM `user` WHERE 
                         username='$user' and password='$pass'");
    $count=mysqli_num_rows($fetch);
    if($count!="")
    {
    session_register("sessionusername");
    $_SESSION['login_username']=$user;
    header("Location:profile.php"); 
    }
    else
    {
       header('Location:index.php');
    }}
?>
```

logout.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(session_destroy())
{
header("Location: index.php");
}
?>
```

session.php

```
<?php
include('db.php');
session_start();
$check=$_SESSION['login_username'];
$session=mysqli_query("SELECT username FROM `user` WHERE username='$check' ");
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($session);
$login_session=$row['username'];
if(!isset($login_session))
{
header("Location:index.php");
}
?>
```

profile.php

```
<?php
include('db.php');
session_start();
$check=$_SESSION['login_username'];
$session=mysqli_query("SELECT username FROM `user` WHERE username='$check' ");
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($session);
$login_session=$row['username'];
if(!isset($login_session))
{
header("Location:index.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: Hey @user3811050, thanks for your question. Are you able to provide details of the errors you're getting? It's a bit hard to troubleshoot without them. Thanks!

Comment: Storing passwords in plaintext is unacceptable. Please don't do that for the sake of your users' safety. (Plain MD5/SHA1 is not ok either. Use e.g. bcrypt or scrypt or AT LEAST salted SHA-256!)

Comment: @ThiefMaster, baby steps. Let's figure out how to do basic PHP first!

Comment: @TheBlueDog, or `$conn->real_escape_string($string);`

Comment: @Aroll605: No, escaping does **NOT** prevent injection.

Comment: @TheBlueDog, How come?

Comment: @Aroll605: Since you asked, [SQL injection that gets around mysql_real_escape_string()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string).

Comment: Voted to close this question.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Do it - typo, blah blah ...

Comment: @TheBlueDog Yeah, big time. I deleted all my comments about what OP wasn't doing, and what they should have done. The question could have easily been avoided. It's been asked so many times, I've lost count. Just a bad question all around, if you ask me ;-) am sure OP probably used my comments and accepted the one below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is something wrong with your db.php file.
You are only supposed to pass 3 parameters,viz, servername, username and password, whereas I see you are passing 4, one being blank.

Please check if

```
 <?php
```

$conn=new mysqli('localhost','root','people');
?>

or

```
 <?php
```

$conn=new mysqli('localhost','','');
?>

works.

Comment: Third one is blank because it contains no password and fourth is database name